# Get incoming URL (referrer) when handling error with .htaccess & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

I would like to grab the incoming URL when an error is thrown. For example, if user inputs `https://example.ca/missing-file123.php` and the `.htaccess` file redirects user to `https://example.ca/error.php?error=404` because `missing-file123.php` does not exist, I would like to know that the user came to `error.php?error=404` from `missing-file123.php` (Or whatever the non-existent URL may be). I've tried using JavaScript `document.referrer` although it returns an empty value (I think because `.htaccess` redirects before client actually visits missing page?). I am looking for a solution using JavaScript, PHP or `.htaccess` to get or push the referrer when an error is being handled. Thanks! (Below is my `.htaccess` file and error page).

ErrorDocuments:

```
ErrorDocument 401 https://example.ca/error.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.ca/error.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.ca/error.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 https://example.ca/error.php?error=500
```

**Note:** I am using full URL's for error documents as they are held in main directory and I want sub directory's to redirect to them as well. Because of this I cannot use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].`

error.php:

```
$error = "";
$errmsg = "";
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['error'], ['401', '403', '404', '500'])) {
        $error = $_GET['error'];
    } else {
        header("location:/");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("location:/");
    exit;
}
```

Here is the rest of my .htaccess file in case there is a conflict with solution:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ homedir/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!homedir/)(.+)$ homedir/$1 [L,NC]

Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore * 
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow, Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

ErrorDocument 401 https://example.ca/error.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.ca/error.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.ca/error.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 https://example.ca/error.php?error=500

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 

SetEnv TZ America/New_York
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 401 https://example.ca/error.php?error=401
> ErrorDocument 403 https://example.ca/error.php?error=403
> ErrorDocument 404 https://example.ca/error.php?error=404
> ErrorDocument 500 https://example.ca/error.php?error=500
> ```

You've set up your `ErrorDocument` directives "incorrectly". By specifying an absolute URL (with scheme and hostname) Apache triggers an external 302 redirect to the error document (exposing the error document to the user) and all information about the URL that triggered the error state is lost. The client sees a 302, not the intended error response code. (In fact, the 401 would fail completely since the browser needs the 401 response to determine whether to display the password dialog.)

You should be using root-relative URLs instead. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?error=500
```

This now triggers an internal subrequest for the error document (the URL that triggered the error response remains the browser's address bar). In fact, there is no need to pass the error code here, since this is available in the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']`.

PHP then provides a number of variables relating to the URL that triggered the error response. For example, use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` (or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) to get the URL that triggered the error/response state. `REQUEST_URI` also includes the query string (if any), but `REDIRECT_URL` contains the URL-path only.

The HTTP `Referer` is not the value you need here. In both cases (internal subrequest and external redirect) the referrer is the URL (if any) from which the URL that triggered the error state was requested. In other words, the URL *before* the URL that triggered the error state.

> Note: I am using full URL's for error documents as they are held in main directory and I want sub directory's to redirect to them as well. Because of this I cannot use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

I'm not sure what "problem" you are trying to resolve here, but using a root-relative URL (starting with a slash) to the error document does not cause issue here and allows any URL (subdirectory, sub-subdirectory etc.) to trigger the error document. (You cannot use a relative URL-path in the `ErrorDocument` directive.)

NB: Since the URL path-depth of the URL that triggers the error state can vary, you must use root-relative URL-paths to your static assets (images, CSS, JS, etc.) in the error document itself, otherwise they will not be found for some requests.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` directive here should simply read:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

You don't need to match everything, you just need to be successful for all requests. The substitution string (ie. `index.php` in your original rule) is simply dropped when using the `F` flag - you should simply use a single hyphen instead to indicate no-substitution. And when using the `F` flag, the `L` flag is implied so can be omitted.

And there's no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive.